# Parse HTML with HTMLParser in Python3

Tags: linux, windows, parsing, python-3.x, html-parsing

I've got a piece of code in Python 3 that successfully parses HTML with HTMLParser in Windows, the problem is that I want to run the script also in Linux and it doesn't seem to be working.

I retrieve the HTML code with the following:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
html_str = str(html)
parse = MyHTMLParser()
parse.feed(html_str)
```

The original output of `html` is the following:

```
b'\n \n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"\n
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n
        <head>\n
```

`html` is in binary, so I convert it to `string` so `parse.feed` doesn't complain. The problem is that the html I get when converting to string is something like this:

```
'b\'\\n \\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"\\n
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\\n
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\\n
    <head>\\n
```

As you can see, I've got several `\\n` that Windows doesn't give a damn about them, but for Linux they're escape sequences, thus failing to parse the html due to them. I don't remember the exact error right now, but it was something like `can't parse \\`

I've tried using `re` to remove the excess of `\` with `re.sub("\\","",html_str)` but in Windows doesn't seem to do anything and in Linux I get also an error.

This is the error I get when trying to `re.sub` the html in Linux:

```
>>> re.sub("\\","",html_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/sre_parse.py", line 194, in __next
    c = self.string[self.index + 1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any idea how can I remove the excess of `\` in `html_str` so I can parse it in Linux?

Comment: `\\n` are not escape sequences on Linux. `\\n` is two characters, a backslash (escaped to ``\\`` to make the output a valid python bytes literal) and a `n` character. These characters have the same meaning on Windows and Linux. Could you please look up the exact error and traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3 you can't convert `bytes` to `str` like you're doing:

```
html_str = str(html)
```

This worked in python2 because `bytes` and `str` were the same, but now you'll get a representation of the original string. To decode the string, you either need to supply the [`encoding`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) argument, or use:

```
hmtl_str = html.decode(encoding)
```

If you can't get the charset from the http headers, you could either try to guess, or use [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to determine the right encoding.

Comment: Note that `str(html, 'ascii')` is the same thing as `html.decode('ascii')`.